# Copy Anchor tag from HTML page to clipboard using Java Script in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, execcommand

I am trying to copy an anchor tag as HTML from web page using JS. The idea is to allow users to copy the anchor element and paste it on word documents as anhcor tag.

HTML code

```
<div id="dummyDiv" style="position: fixed; opacity: 0;">
    <a href="http://localhost/Test">Link to Test</a>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var range = document.createRange();
var selection = window.getSelection();
range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('dummyDiv'));
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange( range );
document.execCommand('copy');
```

The problem I am facing is this script isn't copying it as anchor element. It only copies the inner text of anchor tag "Link To Test". I am not sure how to get it done. Need some help on this.

> **The problem seems to be on dev environment** which is on VM. the same
>   code above works fine outside VM on same versioned chrome. Strange why
>   it isn't working in VM ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use https://clipboardjs.com/ for this.

Thing about clipboard manipulation is: it only works from within a user generated event(click for example). Outside such an event handler, it simply won't put it in the clipboard.

This is my copying code which I use on a click of a button event

```
 clipboard.copy({ 
            'text/plain':'text',
            'text/html': '<strong>text</strong>'
          }).then(
            function(){
                alert("copied to clipboard");
            },
            function(err){
                window.prompt("Something went wrong with automatically copying the data to clipboard.\nPlease press CTRC + C to copy the data",'text');
          });
```

Comment: That is cool. I have checked it and it worked like a charm. But the script is asking for access on Internet Explorer ...and on some cases it asks for activex permission. Any idea how the selection is made for Chrome browser ? I can see they are using an script named "select" to select the node.. looking at it now. Thanks for the help Tschallcka

Comment: well, you are interfacing with a sensitive piece of user space data. I'd wish more browsers would ask for permission.  How it works under the hood? not really sure, it has a legion of fallbacks so it will always try to work.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.13/clipboard.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="bar"><a href="http://localhost/Testasd">Link to Test</a></div>
  <button class="btn"  data-clipboard-target="#bar">
   Cut to clipboard
  </button>
        <script>
           var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

            clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
                e.clearSelection();
            });
        </script>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: You are right about the permission :D but sometimes users are looking for more easy way of doing things and we end up looking for tricks !!

Comment: Hey, it seems the problem was only in my dev environment :( I am not able to figure out the reason but the same code I have pasted in my question works fine on chrome outside my dev VM environment. PS : chrome version also same :D